# Performing bit shift operations (asr, lsl, lsr)

Tags: binary, hex, bit, bit-shift

I am trying to calculate by hand these bit shifting operations, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it. The ARM instructions are:

```
ldr    r0, =0XCAFEBABE
asr    r0, r0, 9
```

I know that asr means arithmetic shift right and that it is equivalent to dividing or multiplying the number by 2.

Another two that I don't know how to do are:

```
ldr    r0, =0XCAFEBABE
lsl    r0, r0, 11
```

For this one, I know how to do a logical shift left, but I'm not sure how it works with shifting 11 bits.

Lastly,

```
ldr    r0, =0XCAFEBABE
lsr    r0, r0, 6
```

For this one, I'm not sure what a logical shift right is.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between *Logical Shift* and *Arithmetic Shift* is that the latter preserves the highest bit.

This behavior of the *Arithmetic Shift* is useful for signed numbers to not change the sign in [*Two's complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). If the highest bit is `1` - indicating a negative number - `1`s are shifted in in a right shift (`asr`) and the highest bit is locked at `1` in a left shift (`asl`). If the highest bit is `0`, this `0` - indicating a positive number - is locked and `0`s are shifted in from the left.

In a *Logical Shift* `0`s are shifted in in both directions (`lsl` and `lsr`). This is useful for unsigned numbers for multiplication and division without remainder, or for bitstream operations.

Now, to solve your task:

- convert the hexadecimal value `CAFEBABE` to a bit representation
- apply the *Logical Shift* or *Arithmetic Shift*
- convert the bit representation to a hexadecimal one

Comment: What do you mean when you say 1s are shifted in a right shift? Does that mean only the ones are shifted?

Comment: An arithmetic shift-right by one will make `10100000` to `11010000` and a shift by two will make `10100000` to `11101000`. So in a way you can say that `1`s are shifted in from the left in an arithmetic shift.